# How to get count of checked checkboxes WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am trying to get Checked numbers from checkbox.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Test x:Key="TestContext"></local:Test>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding number}" Command="{Binding  WhatChecked,Source={StaticResource TestContext},Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding check}" CommandParameter="{Binding check}"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But i can pass only one parameter

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace WpfApplication6
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
/// 
public class DataStruct
{
    public string number {get;set;}
    public bool check {get;set;}
}
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        WhatChecked = new RelayCommand<bool>((e) => Show(e));
        DataStruct DS = new DataStruct();
        DS.check = false;
        DS.number = "101";
        DataStruct DS1 = new DataStruct();
        DS1.check = false;
        DS1.number = "102";
        DataStruct DS2 = new DataStruct();
        DS2.check = false;
        DS2.number = "103";
        testList = new List<DataStruct>();
        TestList.Add(DS);
        TestList.Add(DS1);
        TestList.Add(DS2);
    }
    public ICommand WhatChecked { get; set; }
    private List<DataStruct> testList;
    public List<DataStruct> TestList
    {
        get { return testList; }
        set { testList = value; }
    }
    private void Show(object param)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(param))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Clicked: {0}", param);
        }
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Test();
    }
}
```

}

But i can not pass string with number into command parameter because i already have parameter.

Comment: How it can be resolved in better way?

Answer (score 1):

Since all the items are in the list, and all items are bound to the checkbox `IsChecked` property, you can just search in your list using LINQ

```
TestList.Where(p=>p.check).Count();
```

Comment: Bypass the where and use count directly: `TestList.Count(p=>p.check);`

Comment: I'm not sure where the requirement for a Count came into this - the question seems to refer to the 'number' property of the DataStruct objects, not the number of checked Checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the CommandParameter binding as {Binding} then it'll pass the CheckBox's DataContext (i.e. the entire DataStruct object) as the parameter. This should allow you to access all of the DataStruct properties, rather than just check. Note that many people consider this a violation of MVVM principles in that the ViewModel becomes somewhat more tightly tied to/dependent upon the View. I've used this method a few times where I felt it was necessary to get the job done.

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding number}" Command="{Binding WhatChecked,Source={StaticResource TestContext},Mode=OneWay}" IsChecked="{Binding check}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></CheckBox>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I grok that comment. The current CommandParameter binding is to the check property of the DataStruct object. I'm pretty sure that A191919 is trying to access both the check property *and* the number property of the DataStruct object when the Command fires. The CommandParameter binding I showed above achieves that.

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding}" means to have binding as command parameter ... but the binding is anyway coming from vm

Comment: I don't know what that comment means. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: in short, VM knows about the datacontext of checkbox we do not need to have it as parameter

Comment: You do if you want to use a CommandParameter to pass all of the values of the DataStruct object used as the DataContext of the CheckBox, per the original question. Your suggestion re: using Linq to iterate over the List of DataStructs is a good one, but is a fundamentally different approach to the one used in the poster's code sample.